# How to handle Alerts for ionic app in robot framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, handle

I am trying to automate login page of an ionic app but after click on login button it's showing "bad credentials". I know how to handle pop up alerts but I don't know how to handle these type of alerts. Main challenge in this is there is no locator is showing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrhSu.png)

Comment: you might try sending escape key since it doesn't appear to have a close button... WebElement element = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
  element.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);

Comment: Yeap it is not real browser alert, - you see it is not a Chrome/Firefox/etc modal window. It is just a webelement inserted temporarily in the page source. You just need to find its tag to make a locator.  To find it, just search for its text in the Elements tree while it is shown.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Actually i want to show this alert message in my output result so i tried to find the alert message text but i didn't get this anywhere in the elements.

Comment: Is it possible to try to copy all the HTML from the elements pane while the title is shown? and paste it here?

Comment: <div _ngcontent-pai-c67="" class="row password-login"><div _ngcontent-pai-c67="" class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-center offset-lg-1 offset-xl-1 mt-5 mb-3"><p _ngcontent-pai-c67=""><img _ngcontent-pai-c67="" class="img-fluid pl-4 pr-4 mb-3 bannerlogo"></p><h1 _ngcontent-pai-c67="" class="logotext ion-text-wrap"></h1></div><div _ngcontent-pai-c67="" class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-12 offset-lg-1 offset-xl-2"><div _ngcontent-pai-c67="" class="login-form shadow"><p _ngcontent-pai-c67="" class="text-center mb-2 mt-1">

Comment: <img _ngcontent-pai-c67="" src="assets/imgs/itiLOGO.png"></p><form _ngcontent-pai-c67="" novalidate="" 
class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched"><div _ngcontent-pai-c67="" class="form-group"><input _ngcontent-pai-c67="" type="text" formcontrolname="userId" maxlength="10" 
class="form-control ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="&nbsp;Enter User ID"></div><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-pai-c67="" class="form-group"><input _ngcontent-pai-c67="" type="password" formcontrolname="pass" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" placeholder="&nbsp;Enter Password">

Comment: </div><div _ngcontent-pai-c67="" style="justify-content: start; display: flex; align-items: center;"><input _ngcontent-pai-c67="" type="radio" id="english" value="english" checked="checked" name="language"><label _ngcontent-pai-c67="" for="english">&nbsp; English </label></div><!---->
<!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-pai-c67=""><div _ngcontent-pai-c67="" class="form-group text-right"><a _ngcontent-pai-c67=""class="theme-text" style="cursor: pointer;">Forgot Password?</a></div><a _ngcontent-pai-c67="" class="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-5 p-2 font-18">Login</a>

Comment: </div><!----></form><p _ngcontent-pai-c67="" class="text-center mt-3" style="margin-bottom: -15px;"><img _ngcontent-pai-c67="" src="assets/imgs/Frame 131.png" class="omnilogo"></p></div></div></div><input _ngcontent-pai-c67="" type="text" formcontrolname="userId" maxlength="10" class="form-control ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="&nbsp;Enter User ID"><input _ngcontent-pai-c67="" type="password" formcontrolname="pass" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" placeholder="&nbsp;Enter Password"><a _ngcontent-pai-c67="" class="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-5 p-2 font-18">Login</a>